# How to format/build the data for making timeseries prediction using Python and Pandas?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, data-science

I have went through below blog content about [time-series prediction](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/).

Example for Vanilla LSTM for univariate time series forecasting and it makes a single prediction.

```
# univariate lstm example
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense

# split a univariate sequence into samples
def split_sequence(sequence, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if end_ix > len(sequence)-1:
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequence[i:end_ix], sequence[end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)
 
# define input sequence
raw_seq = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
# choose a number of time steps
n_steps = 3
# split into samples
X, y = split_sequence(raw_seq, n_steps)
# reshape from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, timesteps, features]
n_features = 1
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], n_features))
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=200, verbose=0)
# demonstrate prediction
x_input = array([70, 80, 90])
x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps, n_features))
yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
print(yhat)
```

We can see that the model predicts the next value in the sequence.

```
[[102.09213]]
```

But I have Data about Articles read from various userIds within a year 2019. For now Lets consider a single user or forgot about user. we will consider simple data as ArticleID read for any given dates like below :

**My Data :**

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sdate = date(2019,1,1)   # start date
edate = date(2019,1,7)   # end date
required_dates = pd.date_range(sdate,edate-timedelta(days=1),freq='d')
# initialize list of lists 
data = [['2019-01-01', 1001], ['2019-01-03', 1121] ,['2019-01-02', 1500], 
        ['2019-01-02', 1400],['2019-01-04', 1501],['2019-01-01', 1200],
        ['2019-01-04', 1201],['2019-01-04', 1551],['2019-01-05', 1400]]
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['OnlyDate', 'ArticleID']) 
df1.sort_values(by='OnlyDate',inplace=True)
df = pd.get_dummies(df1.set_index('OnlyDate')['ArticleID']).max(level=0) 
df
                1001    1121    1200    1201    1400    1500    1501    1551
    2019-01-01   1       0       1       0       0       0       0       0
    2019-01-02   0       0       0       0       1       1       0       0
    2019-01-03   0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0
    2019-01-04   0       0       0       1       0       0       1       1
    2019-01-05   0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
    2019-01-06   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

I am not able to transform above given data to make it fit for above LSTM model.

My main objective here is to get predictions for any user Interest(1) for any supplied dates as I have nearly fix 2200 ArticleIDs and nearly 500 userIDs.

What can I try next?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to predict from what? For example, do you want to predict whether a given user reads a given article in the future using the user's reading history?

Comment: @mloning , Yes Exactly, I want to predict whether a given user reads a given article in the future(next 7-15days) using the user's reading history(max history upto 2.5years). please guide me in the proper direction, Thanks

Comment: Given the context, it may be better phrased as a recommendation problem, you should look up recommender systems for that. If you still want to predict whether a user reads a given article, you can make use that article column as your binary target variable and use (time series) classification algorithms. For example, you could try if the previously read articles for a given user can help predict which article they will read next.